# Magic method to run when object is referenced by a variable in an echo statement

Tags: php, lamp

In PHP does such a magic method automatically run when a variable referencing an object is in an echo statement?

Comment: No. You'll just get a `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class yourClass could not be converted to string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, I had quite a difficulty understanding what you're asking. I believe you want the [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method:

> The `__toString()` method allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string. For example, what `echo $obj;` will print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal **E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR** level error is emitted.

Here's a quick example:

```
class A
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'banana';
    }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a;
```

This will print out `banana`